# How to submit data from s:select as ajax in struts 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I have a select tag. `s:select`inside a form. I want to send a post request to the action. I have struts 2 json plugin in place. I am not any in javascript or jquery.

```
<s:form action="selectFileType" method="post"
                             id="selectFileTypeForm">

              <div>
                 <s:select id="select" headerKey=""
                 headerValue="%{getText('uploadAttachmentType.please.select')}"
                        name="uploadAttachmentType" list="attachmentTypeList"
                        required="true" 
                        onchange="this.form.submit();"></s:select>

                    <s:hidden id="declarationObj_ideclare"
                        name="declarationObj.ideclare" />
                    <s:hidden id="declarationObj_completingpersonname"
                        name="declarationObj.completingpersonname" />
                    <s:hidden id="declarationObj_completingpersonofficaltitle"
                        name="declarationObj.completingpersonofficaltitle" />
                    <s:hidden id="declarationObj_completingpersonphone"
                        name="declarationObj.completingpersonphone" />
                    <s:hidden id="declarationObj_completingpersonext"
                        name="declarationObj.completingpersonext" />

                </div>


                  </s:form>
```

`

Comment: can you provide the code that you have tried writing ??

Comment: here is it (added above). It seems struts 2 creates a new action class on each form submission? How to implement a statefull like behavior such that exists in struts 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts 2 has not good tools to perform ajax but you can send post request using jQuery only.

At first you need to find a target element in source code of rendered page and to make selector. It should look something like `select[name='searchEngine'] option:selected`.

Then you can write script that send value of your selected element to `destination_url`. For example:

```
// get element value
var selectedItem = $("select[name='searchEngine'] option:selected").val();
// send post request
$.post("destination_url", {item: selectedItem}, function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

See an example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/2vnsX/18/) and read getting started guide [there](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

That's it.

Comment: I have to disagree on that. Struts2 has great tools to do ajax. See this plugin http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/.

Comment: I disagree that any tag wrapper around JS is a good idea (it isn't a struts2 fault at all). That was the problem with the dojo tags too. If it was a good idea, we'd be writing Java with XML too. The number of unanswered jquery tag questions on here supports that it obscures details, while equivalent jquery only questions would be quickly addressed.